# Can electricity pass through a vacuum layer?

Tags: vacuum

How does electricity behave if the principe of conduction does not apply (or does it)? Does electricity behave as if its conduction value is infinite or does it not pass through the vacuum layer at all?

My hypothesis is that it does pass through the vacuum layer, because the electrons get launched out of the atoms, cause there is too much electrical pressure for them to stay. Also I believe that the electricity would be very evenly spreaded when it arrives through the vacuum, because electrons have the same electrical charge and therefore pull each other away, evenly arranging themselves.

Comment: Electrons can move happily through vacuum of you manage to get them out of the conductor.

Comment: An old CRT certainly sent electrons through a decent vacuum...

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/402544/55662

Comment: Normally vacuum acts as a very good insulator, but if the potential difference between two surfaces is big enough there can be a "vacuum breakdown" where electrons (and atoms) get launched between them, carrying a current.

Comment: Probably the displacement current is relevant to this discussion https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current

Comment: I would like to pedantically emphasize the following:  the region between the cathode and plate of a vacuum tube isn't a vacuum when there is a current through if, by vacuum, one means the absence of particles.  Indeed, even if there isn't a current through, if the cathode is heated, there is an 'electron cloud' surrounding the cathode which is certainly *not* a vacuum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current can flow through vacuum when charge carriers, electrons or ions,  are transported across it. A good example are electronic vacuum tubes where electrons are emitted from a heated cathode filament and transported through vacuum by an applied electric field to a positively charged anode. The current is often controlled by applying a voltage to a grid in the path of this electron flow. Such vacuum tubes where practically the only electronic amplifiers and switches before the advent of solid state transistors. Even today they are used, e.g., in high-power radio transmitters. By application of a high enough electric field electrons can also be emitted from a cold metal into the vacuum by quantum-mechanical tunneling. This effect is called Fowler-Nordheim emission. This effect is e.g. used in cold field effect emitters used in electron microscopes.